# Select a value on multiple columns using like

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

i have a names table containing 4 columns

```
id     fname      mname     lname
1      rain       santos    reyes
2      rocky      blunt     simon
3      greg       hammer    go
```

then i want to select a particular name from the columns fname, mname and lname
using this select i did

```
Select * from account like 'rid%' IN(fname, mname, lname)
```

but it went error. im not really sure with the code.

how could I select a specific like value in the fname mname and lname columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check each column individually and then use `OR` between each one to allow the variable to be in any of the three columns:

```
SELECT * FROM account 
    WHERE fname LIKE 'rid%' 
    OR mname LIKE 'rid%'
    OR lname LIKE 'rid%'
```

Comment: this doesnt take effect sir when i search a value from a post method?

Comment: @user3117337 I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If you still have issues update your original post with more detail and any errors.

Answer (score 0):

For `LIKE` clauses, you have to use `OR` and separate each condition, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM account
WHERE (fname LIKE 'rid%'
       OR mname LIKE 'rid%'
       OR lname LIKE 'rid%')
```

Answer (score -2):

You miss some keywords and have an incorrect syntaxis. Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE "rid%" IN ( `fname` , `mname` , `lname` )
```

Regards.